# why the value in head changes in the code after changes in tail are made

Tags: c++

This is a code to find the n-th term of the linked list from the end .
What I am not able to understand in this is how the value of head changes in ths code.
How it conains the address of the next node.
It should have null pointer in it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

/* Link list Node */
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    Node(int x) {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

/* Function to get the nth node from the last of a linked list*/
int getNthFromLast(struct Node *head, int n);

/* Driver program to test above function*/
int main() {
    int T, i, n, l, k;

    cin >> T;

    while (T--) {
        struct Node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

        cin >> n >> k;
        int firstdata;
        cin >> firstdata;
        head = new Node(firstdata);
        tail = head;

        cout << head->data << endl;
        cout << tail->data << endl;

        cout << head->next << endl;  // output is zero
        cout << tail->next << endl;  // output is zero
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> l;
            cout << head->next << endl;  // output is non zero
            cout << tail->next << endl;  // out put is zero

            tail->next = new Node(l);
            cout << head->next
                 << endl;  // yaha pe head ka address change ho gya hai
            cout << tail->next
                 << endl;  // yaha pe same address hai jo head mein hai
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        // har loop mein head ki value change nhi hogi sirf tail
        // ki change ho rhi hai phir jab loop band ho jaayega uske
        // baad head ki value change ho rhi hai

        cout << head->next << endl;  // 0x55ef55afdeb0
        // YE CHANGE KAISE AAYA ??
        cout << tail->next << endl;  // 0
        cout << getNthFromLast(head, k) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}  // } Driver Code Ends

// Function to find the data of nth node from the end of a linked list.
int getNthFromLast(struct Node *head, int n) {
    int b = 1;
    Node *q = head;
    while (q != NULL) {
        q = q->next;
        b++;
    }
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < (b - (n)); i++) {
        a = head->data;
        head = head->next;
    }
    // DOUBT
    //  how the head data has address of the second node
    return a;
}
```

I tried using `cout` to find different values of head and tail at different times but to no avail.

Comment: Inside `getNthFromLast()`, the command `head=head->next` is executed `(b-n)` times.  If `(b-n)` is less than the number of Nodes in the linked list, then `head` will be non-NULL at the end of the function.

Comment: Note that the `head` referred to in `main()` and the `head` referred to in `getNthFromLast()` are two different variables that just happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
    head = new Node(firstdata);
```

You change it.